# My old boss wants me back but 2 employees may not welcome me

Tags: work-environment, job-offer

I've been at my new job for 4 months but honestly with my skills l feel like I can be more productive at a fast pace setting. I left my old job because I felt overworked; I was drowning and the site director would not listen to me.

When I gave my resignation the Director offered me a raise, a new title, more help ,but at this time it didn't matter as I was ready to go.

I had been there  for 7 years. I stated looking for a new job not too long ago, my old boss found out and would like to meet to see if I'd like to return. He said things will be different, but there are 2 employees that dislike me and are still there.

Should l worried about them if I decide to go back with better pay and a promotion?

Comment: Hello gafese and welcome to The Workplace. How will you interact with those 2 colleagues? Would they be reporting to you?

Comment: Were those 2 colleagues related to the reason you left?

Comment: In your previous job you were overworked and drowning. In your current the pace isn't fast enough. Looks to me like you need to very much not go back to your previous place because it will be better for your health.

Answer (score 3):

Never worry about other employees, you can always deal with those issues as they come up. Your primary concern is getting better pay and promotion. All internal issues are secondary at best. It's not a beauty pageant. I have cheerfully worked with people I absolutely detested both above me and below. But never let it impact on my work which is what I'm being paid for.

Answer (score 3):

I think the close votes are because there really is no way to tell what is right for you.

However, you should not believe that things "will be different" just because the director said so. Organizations don't change easily, and the atmosphere is never dictated by one person but rather by the team as a whole and the business situation. You will be going back to the same people and deal with the same problems as before.

Only you can decide if going back for the promotion is worth it. In my opinion, if the promotion is only incremental you're probably better off moving on to another opportunity.

There is nothing anyone can say about the two people who "dislike" you-- that could mean anything or nothing at all, only you know why and what that really means for you.

Answer (score 1):

I'll say the same than Kilisi, but another way : the important thing is how you build your career. The question for you to know is : do those people have enough influence to screw your resume?

If they are just unpleasant people, well, let them be unpleasant, and forget about them. And I guess they don't have that much power, as they seem not to be able to prevent you from coming back. Wherever you'll go, there will always be people who dislike you, sooner or later.

Coming back to an old job is not common, but it happens, and usually, both sides know why the employee is back. I have never see it happening too bad.